# WS Mqtt with mqttws31.js don't receive messages

Tags: mqtt, node-red, ws

i am need one help. i make a broker with node red and i am using mqtt ws. I tested in Hivemq website and all works good, but in my website i do publish only, and nothing received. i am using mqttws31.js. in my javascript console show conected, and i can publish but never read.  Somebody help me? bellow my code. sorry for my english.\

```
var mqtt;
var reconnectTimeout = 2000;        
var host="my_broker"; //change this     
var port=9001;
function onFailure(msg) {
alert(msg);
    console.log("Connection Attempt to Host "+host+"Failed");
    setTimeout(MQTTconnect, reconnectTimeout);
}
    

function onMessageArrived(msg){
    out_msg="Message received "+ msg.payloadString+"<br>";
    out_msg=out_msg+"Message received Topic "+msg.destinationName;
    console.log(out_msg);
    document.write(msg.payloadString);

    // funcoes executar
    if (msg.destinationName == "voltas") {
        // Temperatura
        alert(msg.payloadString);
    }
}
    
    
function onConnect() {
// Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
    console.log("Connected ");
}

function MQTTconnect() {
    //console.log("connecting to "+ host +" "+ port);
    var x=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000); 
    var cname="orderform-"+x;
    mqtt = new Paho.MQTT.Client(host,port,cname);
    //document.write("connecting to "+ host);
    var options = {
        timeout: 3,
        onSuccess: onConnect,
        onFailure: onFailure,
         };
    mqtt.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived        
    mqtt.connect(options); //connect        
}
```

Comment: The code you've posted never subscribers to ant topics. Also show how you've configured the broker in Node-RED since we need to see if MQTT over Websockets is enabled

Comment: Also what output is there in the browser console?